# Integration of firebase with Angular

Tags: angular, firebase

I am trying to integrate Angular with Firebase, but I am not been able to do so, so any suggestions are welcome.

My files are,
***app.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase) ,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,           
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***app.component.ts***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase}  from '@angular/fire/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  courses:any[];

 constructor (db:AngularFireDatabase) {
    db.list('/courses')
    .subscribe (courses => {
      this.courses = courses;
      console.log(this.courses);
    })
 }

}
```

***app.component.html***

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let course of courses"> 
        {{course.$value}}
    </li> 
</ul>
```

***environment.ts***
export const environment = {
production: false,
firebase : {
apiKey: "AIzaSyDWS........",
etc etc

}
};

***below are the  errors***
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:12:3 - error TS2564: Property 'courses' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
courses:any[];

Error: src/app/app.component.ts:16:17 - error TS7006: Parameter 'courses' implicitly has an 'any' type.
.subscribe (courses => {

Error: src/app/app.component.ts:16:6 - error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'AngularFireList'.
.subscribe (courses => {

**Ideally in the browser it should look like this,**

- course 1
- course 2
- course 3

thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

In your **app.component.ts**:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase}  from '@angular/fire/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 // plz specify the interface for course
 courses$: Observable<any[]> = db.list('/courses').valueChanges()

 constructor (db:AngularFireDatabase) {}

}
```

In your **app.component.html**:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let course of courses$ | async;"> 
        {{course?.$value}}
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks, I had made small changes in the code u provided, with that all the errors are gone,  page is coming but with only bullets , values are not coming , might be some silly mistakes. so the changes I made were,
in app.component.ts file,
export class AppComponent {

  coursera:Observable<any[]>;

constructor (db:AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.coursera  = db.list('/courses').valueChanges()
}
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let course of coursera | async;"> 
        {{course.value}}
    </li> 
</ul>

Comment: Have you checked the request in the developer tools?

Comment: Try to interpolate the `course` value to see the value.

Comment: will check in d afternoon , & will get back to u

Comment: Hello Roman ,
its showing devtools failed to load sourceMap.

Comment: in html file , I have used
 <li *ngFor="let course of courses | async;"> 
        {{course.value}}
    </li>